# Single Page Application accessing public web service: should the client go direct to 3rd party server for data, or via own server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, web-services, single-page-application

I have an Angular application within an ASP.Net MVC page.  It needs to get data from a 3rd party restful service.  Traditionally with a ASP.Net MVC page, I'd get my server code to go to the 3rd party service for the data, marshal the data into .Net domain objects on my server, put those into .Net view models, then serve that data to the client.

With an SPA application, should the (Angular) client app go straight to the 3rd party service for the data which it then puts directly into JavaScript (TypeScript) objects, bypassing the whole .Net server tier?
Going client-to-3rd party feels wrong, but so does the maintainability issue of creating two parallel sets of objects/service calls in TypeScript and .Net along lines of:

Client SPA data request -> my Web API service -> 3rd party service -> data back to my server & into .Net objects -> .Net data returned to SPA & into JavaScript objects -> displayed on client.

Comment: was the 3rd party web service built to be consumed by an application? If so, then I would - assuming it meets your non-functional and security requirements.

Comment: IMHO, your question has little to do with `SPA` nor whatever framework you use. It depends on *both* applications (yours and 3rd party). If there are things like secrets, limits (which by definition will likely have some authorization/access process), paid, etc. then it's more likely that _some_  moving parts will be done server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on multiple factors.  You need to go through ASP if

- It needs some data manipulation with server data , better take care at server side
- If the third party needs authorization by providing a secret key, we cant have the secret key in frontend
- If you need to provide your IP address ( for ex twilio needs to give it your IP address for security)

if the third party do not have authorization ( or if it does and its easy from frontend) and no dependency with your server, I feel you should handle from frontend. No point in duplicating and wasting resources .